# Delphi. How to know if TEvent is Signaled or not?

Tags: delphi, events, signals, terminate

please tell me: how to know if TEvent is Signaled or not?

Click on STOP-button = `SetEvent(Events[1]);`

I am trying to unzip an archive and if STOP-button is pressed then a tread must be terminated and Unzippping must be aborted.

My code:

```
procedure TForm2.ZipForge1OverallProgress(Sender: TObject; Progress: Double;
  Operation: TZFProcessOperation; ProgressPhase: TZFProgressPhase;
  var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  if Events[1]<>null then
  begin
    ThreadUpdating.Terminate;
    Abort;
  end else
    form2.Update_ProgressBar.Position := Trunc(Progress);
end;
```

But if I press STOP-button(SetEvent(Events[1])) nothing happens.

PS: I am using `WaitForMultipleObjects(Event[1],Event[2])` in a thread. Event [1] is being used as a signal of STOP in two parts: in `ZipForge1OverallProgress` and `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025.aspx), but do it properly. You haven't shown that code, and the code you have shown doesn't look right anyway.

First, it looks like you're trying to check whether the `Events[1]` element is a null pointer. Null pointers in Delphi are spelled `nil`, not `null`; the latter is [a *function* that returns a null `Variant` value](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.Null) (but since `Variant` is convertible to lots of other types, the compiler probably doesn't alert you that your code is wrong). Next, it looks as though the event you're handling has a `Cancel` parameter that you can set to notify the caller that it should stop what it's doing, but instead of just setting that, you're throwing an [`EAbort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.EAbort) exception.

If the progress event you show here is really running in a separate thread, then it must not modify property of VCL objects like `TProgressBar`. You need to use `Synchronize` to make sure VCL operations only occur in the VCL thread.

As I said, you need to call `WaitForMultipleObjects` property. That means passing it four parameters, for one thing. You appear to have an array with at least two handles in it, so call it like this:

```
var
  Ret: DWord;

Ret := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @Events[1], False, Timeout);
case Ret of
  Wait_Object_0: begin
    // Events[1] is signaled
  end;
  Wait_Object_0 + 1: begin
    // Events[2] is signaled
  end;
  Wait_Timeout: begin
    // Neither is signaled. Do some more work, or go back to waiting.
  end;
  Wait_Failed: begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```

If all you want to do is *check* whether the handle is signaled, but you don't want to *wait* for it to become signaled if it isn't already, then use a timeout value of zero.

Comment: Good point, I assumed that the handler was called from a synchronized method, but maybe not...

Comment: My code. At first: form2.ZipForge1.ExtractFiles('*.*'); ... then  
ObjectSignal:=WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @Events,false, INFINITE);
if ObjectSignal=WAIT_OBJECT_0 then...;
Event #2 is set with something, we do not care.
Event #1 (Stop-Button): if a press Stop-Button (SetEvent#1) after unzipping  WaitForMultipleObjects will react. But if I push Stop-Button while unzipping? ZipForge must know I pushed the button,must be Aborted and Thread.Terminate must be done. They sad if I would use boolean to check it instead of Event then boolean can be wrong, value can be in cash, so I am using TEvent.

Comment: "They" were talking about using a Boolean to check whether the "stop" button has been pressed, not about using a Boolean to stop further processing of the zip file. "They" have explicitly *given* a Boolean variable for you to fill in (the `Cancel` parameter). You should modify it like the documentation surely tells you to. You don't need to throw an exception. And don't wait infinitely for the event to be signaled — that's counterproductive because you're preventing the zip file from being processed any further.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I've tried so many times trying to understand how `WaitForMultipleObjects`, but couldn't understand it until I read this code example you provided above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'if Events[1]<>null then begin' is this pseudocode?  Doesn't lok like it - looks more like real Delphi to me:)  If so, you are just checking to see if the Event object is assigned, rather than signaled.

If you want to poll the stop event in your OverallProgress handler, you need to call WaitForSingleObject() with a timeout of 0.

Can you not just check a 'stop' boolean in your handler?  This would be much quicker than a kernel call.  You may need the Event as well so that the WFMO call at the top of the thread gets signaled when an abort/terminate is needed or you might get away with signaling some other event in the WFMO array by always checking for stop:

```
TmyThread = class(TThread)
..
public
  stopRequested:boolean;
  procedure stop;
  ..
end;

procedure TmyThread.stop;
begin
  stopRequested:=true;
  someEventInWFMOarray.signal;
end;

procedure TmyThread.execute;
begin;
  while true do
  begin
    waitForMultipeObjects();
    if stopRequested then exit;
    work;
  end;
end;

TForm2.ZipForge1OverallProgress(sender:TObject,......)
begin
  cancel:=TmyThread(Sender).stopRequested;
  if cancel then exit;
  doStuff; 
end;
```

Comment: My code. At first: form2.ZipForge1.ExtractFiles('.'); ... then ObjectSignal:=WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @Events,false, INFINITE); if ObjectSignal=WAIT_OBJECT_0 then...; Event #2 is set with something, we do not care. Event #1 (Stop-Button): if a press Stop-Button (SetEvent#1) after unzipping WaitForMultipleObjects will react. But if I push Stop-Button while unzipping? ZipForge must know I pushed the button,must be Aborted and Thread.Terminate must be done. They sad if I would use boolean to check it instead of Event then boolean can be wrong, value can be in cash, so I am using TEvent.

Comment: @Michael: You can edit your question if you want to provide more information (like add some code example). In comments you can make code more readable by surrounding it with back quote ( \` ) characters.